# No Wi-Fi adaptor found - Ubuntu 20.04.1 after update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I did a fresh install of `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` on my `Lenovo G510` laptop which also runs Windows 10 such that dual boot is enabled. On completion of installation, everything was working fine (I include Wi-Fi in this statement), and I connected to the internet via Wi-Fi. I got an "Update Package" of about 500 MB which I installed and rebooted.

On rebooting Wi-Fi does not seem to work and searching for it in Settings shows `No Wi-Fi adapter found. Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter connected and turned on`.

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu and tried a couple of solutions on the forum which don't seem to have made a difference. I really don't want to keep trying without really understanding the issue and which could only make my situation worse. Let me know any information needed which can help diagnose the issue.

```
~$ sudo lshw -class network -short
H/W path         Device      Class          Description
=======================================================
/0/100/1c.1/0                network        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
/0/100/1c.2/0    enp3s0      network        QCA8172 Fast Ethernet


~$  lspci | grep -i broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Need info on your wi fi adapter.

Comment: @David I've edited my post with information about the adapter, hopefully that's what you're looking for. `BCM43142 802.11b/g/n`